# Why does SymPy's factorint function take up so much RAM and why doesn't turning off cache fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

First let me say I've tried everything I could think of, after checking pretty much everywhere I could think of. Here is an example of the type of program I'm writing:

```
from sympy.ntheory import factorint
x = 10 ** 10
while True:
    print(str(factorint(x)))
    x += 1
```

No amount of clear_cache(), environ["SYMPY_USE_CACHE"]="no", or environ["SYMPY_TRACE_INT"]="no", (the three solutions I could find) make any dent in the gigantic amount of RAM that SymPy's factoring takes up, and what's worse is that it seems like after each number, the cached whatever just...stays there, hogging space, resulting in RAM ballooning to Gigabytes within minutes. Is there anything I can do? What other factorization functions out there exist for use with Python? I couldn't find much else out there...Thanks in advance.